# Find the conflict package in Bower and find the right package to install

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, bower

I'm using [SpBowerBundle](https://github.com/Spea/SpBowerBundle) to manage JS libraries on my Symfony2 project. It was working until days ago when any time I try to upgrade a package, I get this error:

```
bower        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for moment
```

I suspect that the problem is on my `bower.json` file due to a package version I'm using. This is the content of the mentioned file:

```
{
    "name": "AppBundle",
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "latest",
        "jquery-migrate": "latest",
        "bootstrap": "latest",
        "font-awesome": "latest",
        "bootstrapvalidator": "master",
        "pwstrength-bootstrap": "latest",
        "select2": "latest",
        "fuelux": "latest",
        "moment": "master",
        "x-editable": "latest",
        "datatables": "latest",
        "bootbox": "latest",
        "knockout": "latest",
        "jquery-file-upload": "latest"
    }
}
```

Then,

- How do I find the conflict package? Any log?
- How do I install the latest release of each package? I mean which string I should use ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conflicting package is "moment", you can see it the error message:

```
bower        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for moment
```

Using the latest version of bower you can get more information about the conflict:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for moment, please choose one:
    1) moment#master which resolved to d5ff2cfc00 and is required by AppBundle
    2) moment#2.7.0 which resolved to 2.7.0 and is required by fuelux#3.2.1
```

There is a conflict between the moment dependency set in your bower.json and the one required by "fuelux".
To resolve the conflict, you can add the following to your bower.json to force a specific version of moment:

```
"resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.7.0"
  }
```

Comment: LOL!  I'm a build engineer troubleshooting a log without any real knowledge of NPM and I took "moment" to mean "for the moment" as in try again later! :)